# how to import wikipedia in to python code?

Tags: python, project

though I install it as pip install Wikipedia, it shows me a error Import "wikipedia" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)

I try to reinstall the Wikipedia and also upgrade the pip version

Comment: Not enought details, so I can only guess: Maybe not using same python for `pip` and `pylance`. Or maybe you use `venv` and not installed in the venv.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are a little confused, let's start from the pylance:

Pylance is an extension that works alongside Python in Visual Studio Code to provide performant language support. So pylance is not a tool that has any effect on the code you wrote or the pip libraries.

If you want to use Wikipedia library, you should follow these steps;

Activate virtual environment or directly use it on console:

```
pip install Wikipedia
```

And you can start the use;

```
import wikipedia

wikipedia.search("Stackoverflow")
```

If you want to get a definite result, instead of trying to install Wikipedia with pylance, proceed by installing it from the console.

Wikipedia pypi page:
https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/